# Insert ...on duplicate in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle and I want to check if particular primary key value is present or not. If value exists then just update the entire row .If value is not present, then insert new row.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Code above works on MySql. How to achieve the same in Oracle 10g? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the SQL standard [MERGE](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) statement, which is supported by (more recent versions of) Oracle.  This will work with other DBMS than Oracle too.